# Burn - Show a custom screen along with application window

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, c#-4.0, wix

I have added the source code for wix theme and customized the default one with what i required.

```
 <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkLicense">
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseUrl="" ThemeFile="HyperlinkTheme.xml" LocalizationFile="HyperlinkTheme.wxl"  LogoFile="header3.jpg"/>
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>
```

Now when i click the installer, the installer main window opens with `Install` and `Cancel` button.I need to show a custom screen with product name and version and `OK` button before this screen loads.On clicking OK should close this custom screen and open the main installer screen.

I googled and found that if i am not using any default screen i can customize the screen.Since i am using default installer screen i don't know how to do this and how it works.Need some idea to do this in Burn/Bundle.wxs.

Answer (score 1):

WixStandardBootstrapperApplication does not support this today.  The logic behind navigating between pages is [hard coded](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/ext/BalExtension/wixstdba/WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.cpp).

Comment: Is it possible with pure custom screen and not using WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.

Comment: You can create a [custom BA](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/ba/).  Here's some [documentation](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Documentation-for-creating-a-Managed-Bootstrapper-Application-for-WiX-Burn-td7594088.html) on making a C# BA.

Comment: Is it possible to force the exe  of BA to open under Administrator previlage.

Comment: No (http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Bootstrapper-manifest-td7582666.html)